# Keeping a specific filter applied when clicking 'Clear' in Sort & Filter in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel 2013, under the Data ribbon, Sort & Filter section, the button "Clear" clears all filters.

Is it possible to do something like "clear all filters but this one"?

I frequently want to clear filters from several columns at once, except for one specific filter. My current solution is to clear filters, and reapply the one I wanted to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing out of the box, AFAIK. But you can roll your own:

With several filters in place, fire up the macro recorder, clear all filters, re-apply the one you want to keep, stop the macro recorder. Assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut or put a shape button on the sheet and assign it to the macro.

Remember that the file needs to be saved as a macro-enabled .xlsm workbook.

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as accepted if a macro-free answer isn't given soon. I suspect this will be the accepted answer.